# Prevent header click on grouped Office UI Fabric DetailsList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I have an Office UI Fabric [Grouped DetailsList](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/detailslist/grouped) with an `onActiveItemChanged` event. I want the event not to fire when user clicks on the **group header** itself. The event should fire only when user clicks on a row.

I've found no property that gives that behaviour, so instead I've tried this approach:

```html
<DetailsList
    onActiveItemChanged={doSomething}
    groupProps={{
      onRenderHeader: _onRenderGroupHeader
    }}
</DetailsList>
```

```js
function _onRenderGroupHeader(props) {
    return (
        <div>
          {props.group.name}
        </div>
    );
};
```

That works in both Chrome and Edge, but in IE11 the `onActiveItemChanged` event is still fired.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any other way to solve it but with this trick:

```
const doSomething = (item, index, event) => {

    // IE 11 hack
    if (event.target.classList.contains('ms-List-cell')) {
        return false;
    }

    // navigate code here
}
```